# SUNION for all keys with the same pattern in Redis

Tags: redis

I have n keys with the same pattern `key:abc:<id>` that store unsorted set. I want to do the union for them all, but according to Redis documentation (https://redis.io/commands/sunion) I can only specify separate keys in the command like `SUNION key:abc:1 key:abc:2 key:abc:3`

I want something like `SUNION key:abc:*`

Comment: Did you get any solution for this?

Comment: Unfortunately, I still did not have any solution yet